# Exporting DOORS Objects to csv files with dxl wont write all objects?

Tags: python, string, csv, ibm-doors

I wrote a script for DOORS 9.5 that looks in a DOORS module for specific Objects and writes them in a csv-file. However after a specific number of lines it stops writing in the csv-file and i got only half of my requested Objects.
I'm using a String replacement function that i found in the internet. So thats maybe the problem or is there some kind of maximum for dxl to write in csv files?

Would be very nice if anyone could help me with this, because i cant find any solution for this in the internet or understand why this wont work.

```
// String replacement function
string replace (string sSource, string sSearch, string sReplace) 
{
int iLen = length sSource
if (iLen == 0) return ""

int iLenSearch = length(sSearch)

if (iLenSearch == 0) 
{ 
    print "search string must not be empty"
    return "" 
}

// read the first char for latter comparison -> speed optimization
char firstChar = sSearch[0]

Buffer s = create() 
int pos = 0, d1,d2;    
int i

while (pos < iLen) { 
    char ch = sSource[pos]; 
    bool found = true

    if (ch != firstChar) {pos ++; s+= ch; continue}
    for (i = 1; i < iLenSearch; i++) 
       if (sSource[pos+i] != sSearch[i]) { found = false; break }
    if (!found) {pos++; s+= ch; continue}
    s += sReplace
    pos += iLenSearch
}

string result = stringOf s
delete s
return result
}

Module m = read(modulePath, false)
Object o
string s
string eval

Stream outfile = write("D:\\Python\\Toolbeta\\data\\modules\\test.csv")
for o in m do
{
eval = o."Evaluation Spec Filter"
if(eval == "Evaluation Step Object")
{
    s = o."Object Text"
    s = replace(s,"\n","\\n")
outfile2 << o."HierarchyNumber" ";" s "\n"
}
}
close outfile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution to my problem (I know the replace function was kinda crappy^^).
dxl scripts seem to have an internal timer. When the timer is up, the script will end itself automaticly even when processes are still executed. So my script always stoppt after x seconds and thats the reason i never got all the data in my csv files.
If you have the same problem try `pragma runLim,0`. It sets the timer to unlimited. you can also choose a timer by replacing 0 with any number. (For my purpose 2000000 suits the best).

Thx for all answers and the help

Answer (score 0):

There is no line limit that I know of for output to CSV.

But I do see something odd in your replace function. Your `sSearch` variable is always `\n` which as far as DOORS is concerned is 1 character (a carriage return). But in the following line `i=1` :

```
if (sSource[pos+i] != sSearch[i]) { found = false; break }
```

`sSearch` doesn't have any character at position `1` because the string array starts at `0`.

I think you need to change your for loop to:

```
for (i = 0; i < iLenSearch; i++)
```

My guess is that your script is failing the first time it finds an object with a carriage return in it.

Let me know if that helps, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There are a myriad of problems you have to take care of when outputting Object Text to a CSV. Are you taking care of replacing commas, or at least quoting the text? What if the Object Text has an OLE in it? Etc.

If you are doing this manually, I would suggest setting up a view with the attributes you want to see as columns and a filter to include only the objects you want to see, then using the native DOORS export to Excel (Module window: File > Export > Microsoft Office > Excel). If you really need a CSV, you can then save from Excel as CSV.

If you are doing this automatically with scripts, I would suggest using a DXL library for Excel, such as: http://www.baselinesinc.com/dxl-repository/

*(But be aware there are problems using Excel in Windows Scheduled Tasks.)*

If you don't have access to Excel, then you might look around the 'net for some C code used to write to a CSV and base your DXL on that.

Hope that helps.

EDIT: Also, here's a link for a good function for escaping: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014627043